# MongoDb - Analytics Platform Considerations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, analytics

I have a web app running with Mongo that is working very well to power the app. The main collection of my schema is designed to power the user functionality in the easiest way. Here's a brief example of how that document is structured:

```
var RowSchema = new Schema({
  value: String,
  createdAt:{
    type: Date,
    'default': Date.now
  }
});

var ColumnSchema = new Schema({
  rows: [RowSchema],
  createdAt:{
    type: Date,
    'default': Date.now
  }
});

var ItemSchema = new Schema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    'default': shortid.generate
  },
  name: String,
  columns: [ColumnSchema],
  createdAt:{
    type: Date,
    'default': Date.now
  }
})
```

As you might have guessed, the data structure represent a board with columns/rows.  I want to collect metrics on actions to this document, so adding/removing columns/rows, changing values, deleting, etc..

Is it better in mongo to have distinct events in time or have a single document store counts? Example would be if you added three rows you would have three documents vs a single document with a count of three?  I would think the former so its more time series based? For distinct events should they each have their own collection? Seems to normalized to me.

What are some tips with this when thinking about counts vs aggregation?